# trying to create a new rails admin user on heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In the heroku console I'm entering

```
Admin.create(email:‘me@gmail.com’,username: ‘Me’,password:’pass’,password_confirmation:’pass’)
```

When I run this I get

```
SyntaxError: (irb):16: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...reate(email:‘me@gmail.com’,username: ‘Me’,p...
...                               ^
(irb):16: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
...me@gmail.com’,username: ‘Me’,password:’pass...
```

Can anyone help with what's wrong with my Admin.create code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like dodgy quotation marks, or spacing?  Does this work? (copy & paste)

```
Admin.create(email: 'me@gmail.com', username: 'Me', password: 'pass', password_confirmation: 'pass')
```

Comment: Thanks - yes, you were right it was dodgy quotation marks. All sorted now.